# Route naked domain/root in iPage & Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, root, appdomain

I currently have a Rails App located at http://www.joedayvie.com; however, when you visit the root (joedayvie.com), it points to my other, initial website in my account (http://www.dayvie.com). Does anyone have any idea how to link the root of joedayvie.com?

I had a previous Rails App on an account and the root worked properly but cannot seem to make it work this time. I added the root to Heroku via the terminal and added a CNAME (host: www and points to: myherokuapplink).

If you have any other information, please let me know - Thank you! =)

Joe

Edit: I was under the impression I have to edit the A Record in the DNS; however, I don't know how I would find the IP address to change it too. I notice that both domains share the same IP address so it would make sense if this were the issue. Ideas on where I could find what IP address to change it too?

Answer (score 1):

A records require an IP address and Heroku apps do not have stable inbound IP addresses.

CNAME, ALIAS and ANAME will work with Heroku.

Alternatively, you can set up a 301 redirect from joedayvie.com to http://www.joedayvie.com.

See this link (or let me know in the comments) if you need more information on custom domains with Heroku.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: Hey there, thank you! I actually resolved this issue by contacting the hosting company and they helped me through settings on their end which needed to be made. It was outside the DNS portion too.